# Computing the Distance

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal

I'm having a little difficulty getting this problem down.  I've been trying to follow my notes, but I guess I'm not doing it correctly.  Anyone know how to properly answer this question?

> > Let $\vec{y}$ = $
> >   \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
> >    8 \\
> >    5 \\
> >   -5 \\
> >   \end{array} } \right]$
> >     and $\vec{u}$ = $
> >   \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
> >    4 \\
> >    4 \\
> >    4 \\
> >   \end{array} } \right]$.
> >     Compute the distance $d$ from $\vec{y}$ to the line through $\vec{u}$ and the origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The squared distance from $(8,5,-5)$ to a point $(4t,4t,4t)$ on the line is
$$(8-4t)^2+(5-4t)^2+(-5-4t)^2=48t^2-64t+114.\tag{1}$$
This is minimal at $t=64/96=2/3$ so that the nearest point on the line is $(8/3,8/3,8/3).$
Or since you only need the distance, plug $t=2/3$ into (1) and get $278/3$, and the distance is the squareroot of that.

NOTE: The line could be more simply $(t,t,t)$ which would make for smaller coefficients in (1).

Answer (score 4):

$$d=\left|\vec{y}-\frac{\vec{y}\cdot\vec{u}}{|\vec{u}|}{\vec{u}}\right|$$
Then
$$d=\left|\begin{pmatrix}8\\5\\-5\end{pmatrix}-\frac{32}{4\sqrt{3}}\begin{pmatrix}4\\4\\4\end{pmatrix}\right|$$

I'll leave the rest to you

Answer (score 1):

You can think of $\vec{y}$ as being the sum of two vectors: a vector $\vec{y}_p$ parallel to the line through $\vec{u}$ and the origin, and a vector $\vec{y}_o$ orthogonal to that line.

The $d$ you need to compute is the length of $\vec{y}_o$.

$\vec{y}_p$ is the projection of $\vec{y}$ onto the line through $\vec{u}$ and the origin.  The length of $\vec{y}_p$ is equal to the absolute value of the dot product $\vec{y}\cdot\vec{u}'$ where $\vec{u}'$ is a unit vector in the same direction as $\vec{u}$.

Knowing the length of $\vec{y}$ and the length of $\vec{y}_p$ you can use the Pythagorean Theorem to get the length of $\vec{y}_o$.